# Rails app: Same Active Record and Webrick Errors in both VSCode & RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, visual-studio-code, debugging, activerecord, vscode-debugger

I switched editors from Atom to VS Code and I'm working on a Rails app. Debugging Ruby in VS Code has proved challenging. I'm using the rdbg extension in VSCode for the debugging. I see two errors when launching the VSCode debugger either by pressing the green button or running `bundle exec rdbg --open -n -c -- bundle exec rails s` in the terminal. I see the exact same errors when I opened up the app in RubyMine, thinking that Ruby-ist editor would fare better. It didn't -- so this lets me think it's an issue of my versions not being aligned:

**There are two errors: the first presumably about Active Record and the second presumably about webrick. Here's the entire error stack:**

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (could not translate host name "db" to address: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
):
  
activerecord (7.0.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:87:in `rescue in new_client'
activerecord (7.0.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:77:in `new_client'
activerecord (7.0.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:37:in `postgresql_connection'
activerecord (7.0.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:656:in `public_send'
activerecord (7.0.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:656:in `new_connection'
activerecord (7.0.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:700:in `checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (7.0.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:679:in `try_to_checkout_new_connection'
activerecord (7.0.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:640:in `acquire_connection'
activerecord (7.0.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:341:in `checkout'
activerecord (7.0.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:181:in `connection'
activerecord (7.0.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_handler.rb:211:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (7.0.8) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:313:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (7.0.8) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:280:in `connection'
activerecord (7.0.8) lib/active_record/migration.rb:648:in `connection'
activerecord (7.0.8) lib/active_record/migration.rb:643:in `build_watcher'
activerecord (7.0.8) lib/active_record/migration.rb:625:in `block in call'
activerecord (7.0.8) lib/active_record/migration.rb:624:in `synchronize'
activerecord (7.0.8) lib/active_record/migration.rb:624:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (7.0.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:99:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:28:in `call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:29:in `call'
railties (7.0.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:40:in `call_app'
railties (7.0.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `block in call'
activesupport (7.0.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (7.0.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
activesupport (7.0.8) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
railties (7.0.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:93:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:23:in `call'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:138:in `call'
webpacker (5.4.4) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:25:in `perform_request'
rack-proxy (0.7.7) lib/rack/proxy.rb:87:in `call'
railties (7.0.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:530:in `call'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:95:in `service'
webrick (1.8.1) lib/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
webrick (1.8.1) lib/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
webrick (1.8.1) lib/webrick/server.rb:310:in `block in start_thread'

ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 3)
        from /Users/diana.eromosele/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionview-7.0.8/lib/action_view/base.rb:227:in `initialize'
        from /Users/diana.eromosele/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/web-console-3.5.1/lib/web_console/template.rb:19:in `new'
        from /Users/diana.eromosele/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/web-console-3.5.1/lib/web_console/template.rb:19:in `render'
        from /Users/diana.eromosele/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/web-console-3.5.1/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:36:in `block in call'
        from /Users/diana.eromosele/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/web-console-3.5.1/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
        from /Users/diana.eromosele/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/web-console-3.5.1/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
        from /Users/diana.eromosele/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:29:in `call'
        from /Users/diana.eromosele/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:40:in `call_app'
        from /Users/diana.eromosele/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `block in call'
        from /Users/diana.eromosele/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
        from /Users/diana.eromosele/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
        from /Users/diana.eromosele/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
        from /Users/diana.eromosele/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `call'
        from /Users/diana.eromosele/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:93:in `call'
        from /Users/diana.eromosele/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
        from /Users/diana.eromosele/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
        from /Users/diana.eromosele/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
        from /Users/diana.eromosele/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
        from /Users/diana.eromosele/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:23:in `call'
        from /Users/diana.eromosele/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
        from /Users/diana.eromosele/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:138:in `call'
        from /Users/diana.eromosele/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/webpacker-5.4.4/lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:25:in `perform_request'
        from /Users/diana.eromosele/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-proxy-0.7.7/lib/rack/proxy.rb:87:in `call'
        from /Users/diana.eromosele/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/railties-7.0.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:530:in `call'
        from /Users/diana.eromosele/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/rack-2.2.8/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:95:in `service'
        from /Users/diana.eromosele/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/webrick-1.8.1/lib/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
        from /Users/diana.eromosele/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/webrick-1.8.1/lib/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
        from /Users/diana.eromosele/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/webrick-1.8.1/lib/webrick/server.rb:310:in `block in start_thread'
```

Do I need to update some gems?